# configuring Synonyms.txt in AWS hosted elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload sysnonyms.txt in AWS hosted elastic search, but I couldn't find any feasible way to do that. All I have tried is the following.

I am not supposed to use inline sysnonym, since i have a huge list of synonmys. So I tried to use below settings to uplaod synonyms.txt to AWS hosted elastic search,

```
 "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                   "synonyms_filter" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                       "synonyms_path" : "https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/synonyms.txt"
                    }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                    "synonyms_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter" : ["lowercase","synonyms_filter"]
                    }
                    }
                }
```

when I use above settings to create index from Kibana(VPC access), I am getting below exception.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[0jc0TeJ][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/create]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"IOException while reading synonyms_path_path:  (No such file or directory)"}},"status":400}
```

Since my Elastic search is hosted my AWS, I cant get node details or etc folder details to upload my file.

Any suggestion on the approach or how to upload file to AWS ES?

Answer (score 4):

The AWS ES service [has many limitations](https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service), one of which is that you cannot use file-based synonyms (since you don't have access to the filesystem).

You need to [list all your synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) inside the index settings.

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
               "synonyms_filter" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [                    <--- like this
                        "i-pod, i pod => ipod",
                        "universe, cosmos"
                    ]
                }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                "synonyms_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase","synonyms_filter"]
                }
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

You can now use file-based synonyms in AWS ES by adding [custom packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html)

Comment: can these synonyms be added at runtime (without having to close the index) ?

Comment: @RaghunandanJ In order to update synonyms, you need to update the index analyzer settings and closing/reopening the index is [mandatory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) for that operation to work.